# Multiclass dataset preprocessing gave "nan" error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

While preprocessing a dataset I'm facing

```
DF
    ID  Age Gender  Height  Weight  BMI Label
0   1   25  Male    175.0   80  25.3    Normal Weight
1   2   30  Female  160.0   60  22.5    Normal Weight
2   3   35  Male    180.0   90  27.3    Overweight
3   4   40  Female  150.0   50  20.0    Underweight
4   5   45  Male    190.0   100 31.2    Obese
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
103 106 11  Male    175.0   10  3.9 Underweight
104 107 16  Female  160.0   10  3.9 Underweight
105 108 21  Male    180.0   15  5.6 Underweight
106 109 26  Female  150.0   15  5.6 Underweight
107 110 31  Male    190.0   20  8.3 Underweight


DF.isnull().sum()

DF['Height']=DF['Height'].fillna(DF['Height'].median())

most_frequent_category = DF['Gender'].mode().iloc[0]
DF['Gender'].fillna(most_frequent_category, inplace = True)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

DF['Gender']=le.fit_transform(DF['Gender'])
DF['Label']=le.fit_transform(DF['Label'])

value_count = DF.groupby('Label').size().reset_index(name = 'count')
print(value_count)

z_score = (DF['Age']-DF['Age'].mean())/DF['Age'].std()
print(z_score)

for i in z_score:
  if i<-3:
    print ("We have Outlier", i)
  elif i>3:
    print ("We have Outlier", i)
  else:
    continue

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(font_scale = 2) #fixing the font size of the visualization to 2

plt.subplots (figsize = (15,15)) 

heat_plot = sns.heatmap(DF.corr(method='pearson'), annot=True, cmap='Spectral',annot_kws={'size':20})

plt.yticks(fontsize = 15)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 15)
plt.show()

correlations = DF.corr(method='pearson')
print(correlations['Label'].sort_values(ascending = False).to_string())

DF['Label'].iloc[0:150]

from sklearn.utils import shuffle  
shuffled_DF = shuffle(DF)

rearranged_DF = shuffled_DF.reset_index(drop = True)
X = rearranged_DF.drop(columns=['Label'])
y = rearranged_DF['Label']

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler() 
Standard_Scaled_X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
print(Standard_Scaled_X)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Standard_Scaled_X,y, test_size = 0.20)


print("train data size (features): ", len(x_train))  
print("train data size (target): ", len(y_train)) 

print("test data size (features): ", len(x_test))
print("test data size (target): ", len(y_test))

print(x_train)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
NB_Classifier = GaussianNB(priors=None, var_smoothing=1e-09)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

k_fold = KFold(10)

accuracy = cross_val_score(NB_Classifier, x_train,y_train, cv = k_fold, scoring = 'accuracy')
precision = cross_val_score(NB_Classifier, x_train,y_train, cv = k_fold, scoring = 'precision')
recall = cross_val_score(NB_Classifier, x_train,y_train, cv = k_fold, scoring = 'recall')
f1_score = cross_val_score(NB_Classifier, x_train,y_train, cv = k_fold, scoring = 'f1')
AUC = cross_val_score(NB_Classifier, x_train,y_train, cv = k_fold, scoring = 'roc_auc')

ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another 
average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].

print(accuracy)
overall_accuracy = sum(accuracy)/len(accuracy)

print(overall_accuracy)

print(precision)
overall_precision = sum(precision)/len(precision)
print(overall_precision)

output: nan
```

I had to add the whole code here.
Accuracy value is giving me right output, but precision/recall/f1_score/AUC values are giving me nan as output. How can I resolve it?

Comment: "*I had to add the whole code here*" - what's he logic of including a whole bunch of `print` statements here (and plot commands) without showing their output? Please re-read how to create a [mre] - emphasis on *minimal*, and trim out any parts of code that are actually irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Also, there seems to be e `ValueError` buried inside your code! Please do **not** do that - post *only* the code until the error is produced, and the error message separately (and clearly) outside your code block. Plus, the `ValueError` already tells you something important - have you looked at it?

Comment: In other words, your actual issue here is not the `nan`, it is the `ValueError` you get, and this is where you should focus your attention (and your question, too); it explains the `nan`, too.